# How to mount SMB share from terminal using keychain?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, mount, smb

I need to be able mount a SMB share from terminal, for MAC OS versions (10.7). Is there a way to use mount_smbfs with keychain so I don't get prompt the username/password or have to add it to the command? I'm quite new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should ask you if you want to save credentials when you mount it. You could write a script that auto-mounts on boot if you want to, I actually have that on mine, I could post it. But if you need to stay in terminal, that won't be useful

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian. The reason I need it to stay in terminal is because I am writing a Fabric script for deployment and would like to make it generic for each computer to use be able to use the credentials stored in the keychain rather than add it to the command. Hope that make sense